# How do I create a 'list of variables used in my program'?

Tags: java, variables

I'm currently making a program for a grocery store for a computer project in school. It's very, very basic Java (it works on the terminal window).

We have been asked to include a variable list in our files when we submit our hard copy of the project. This variable list has to basically be a table where each and every variable, it's data type and it's use has been mentioned.

As you can guess, with more than 200 variables, this is pretty difficult. Is there a way I can automate this process? I will have to type out the uses of each of them, but is there any way I can at least 'extract' the variable and their data types?

Just so you know, my Java knowledge is very basic but I can work my way through arrays, functions, strings and everything.

EDIT: Okay, so here's an example -

```
int x=5, g=7; 
for (int i=0; i++; i<10) 
{
     x++;
     g=x+x;
     System.out.println(g);
     System.out.println(x);
}
```

If this was my program, here's what my teacher wants :

[image]

In this particular example, g and x don't really have any use. But in my program, all the variables are very much being used.

If it still isn't clear, I'll just create a variable list for an actual program and send it along.

As for NoSQL - I have no idea what that is. I'm 15. Sorry.

Comment: If you're doing "basic" java for school, why do you have over 200 variables?  Are you referring to each index of arrays/lists as a variable or something?

Comment: Are you asking about a way to automate the process of making a table of all of your variables?  Or are you asking about a way to reduce the number of variables you use in your program?  Unclear what you're question is.

Comment: There's about 15 functions in my program, each dealing with a specific job  in the store. So, there's different variables for inputting the cost, the quantity, etc. I'm surprised too but in the end the number of variables did come up to 200. And yes, each array has to be treated as a different 'variable' where, if the array has only integers in it, it's defined as int[]. What I meant by basic is that we aren't even using JFrame or anything. We're only working with loops, switch cases and all of that. I'm sorry if it wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: I only need a way to automate the process of making the table. Again, sorry if it wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: you can generate java docs of your code, which will help you to document your variables easily.

Comment: How do I make a Java doc? Are there any good tutorials I can work with?

Comment: You can use eclipse or any other good java IDE to complete this job.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html

Comment: Will this work with BlueJ? I did see something like Documentation in it but I keep receiving a critical error when I go there. My program works fine but that doesn't.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to automate that. A variable "meaning" is not something that can be guessed by a machine. You should 1/ figure out why you have so much variables 2/ do the table by hand.

Comment: http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~schmidt/300f04/bluej.packages.html go through section 2

Comment: Damn it. What I was thinking is that all my integers will obviously contain an 'int' in front of them. If I could somehow include all the ints AND the words in front of them (these would be the variables), that would do it. The same goes for Strings. I'll just have to hunt the arrays and include them but they aren't that many anyway. But how do I do it?